# How can I set the display range of a QGraphicItemGroup?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, qgraphicsitem

I have a QGraphicsItemGroup aggregating several child items, and I want to show only part of the group.(not the numbers of child items, area). Just like the image here.

[image: Image is here!]

I want to show the display area.

To do that, I have tried the override the QGraphicsItemGroup::boundingRect(). However, nothing have happened. And i find this in QT docs, maybe this is the reason why doesn't work.

***The boundingRect() function of QGraphicsItemGroup returns the bounding rectangle of all items in the item group.***

Also, I know I can change the size of QGraphicsView to make it work. However I put the View as CentralWidget, as I also need to display other object in the View, I can not change the size of the View.

How can I set the display range of a QGraphicItemGroup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform this task we can overwrite `shape()` by returning a `QPainterPath` that defines the visible region, so that it spreads to its children we enable the flag `ItemClipsChildrenToShape`:

```
class GraphicsItemGroup: public QGraphicsItemGroup{
public:
    GraphicsItemGroup(QGraphicsItem * parent = 0):QGraphicsItemGroup(parent){
        setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemClipsChildrenToShape, true);
    }
    QPainterPath shape() const
    {
        if(mShape.isEmpty())
            return QGraphicsItemGroup::shape();
        return mShape;
    }
    void setShape(const QPainterPath &shape){
        mShape = shape;
        update();
    }

private:
    QPainterPath mShape;
};
```

Example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    w.setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);

    QGraphicsView view;
    QPushButton button("click me");

    w.layout()->addWidget(&view);
    w.layout()->addWidget(&button);

    view.setScene(new QGraphicsScene);
    GraphicsItemGroup group;
    view.scene()->addItem(&group);
    auto ellipse = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(QRectF(0, 0, 100, 100));
    ellipse->setBrush(Qt::red);
    auto rect = new QGraphicsRectItem(QRect(150, 150, 100, 100));
    rect->setBrush(Qt::blue);
    group.addToGroup(ellipse);
    group.addToGroup(rect);

    QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, [&group](){
        QPainterPath shape;
        if(group.shape().boundingRect() == group.boundingRect()){
            shape.addRect(0, 50, 250, 150);
        }
        group.setShape(shape);
    });

    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/47972795).

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what i want! Just a question. As i konw,QGraphicItem.shape() seems to be similar to boundingRect(). In my case Why boundingRect does't work but shape() does it?

Comment: **boundingRect()**: ... defines the outer bounds of the item as a rectangle; all painting must be restricted to inside an item's bounding rect. QGraphicsView uses this to determine whether the item requires redrawing.

Comment: **shape()**: Returns the shape of this item as a QPainterPath in local coordinates. The shape is used for many things, including collision detection, hit tests, and for the QGraphicsScene::items() functions. The default implementation calls boundingRect() to return a simple rectangular shape, but subclasses can reimplement this function to return a more accurate shape for non-rectangular items. For example, a round item may choose to return an elliptic shape for better collision detection. , that is, the first defines where to paint and the other defines what is visible. :P

Comment: Thank u very much!